# Issues with jquery slide up - slidedown - The div doesn't appear

Tags: jquery, css

I've some problem with jquery SlideDown.
I think the problem is in the display:none of css but I need to start with the div hidden.

**HTML**

```
    <div id="miao">CIAO</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
   var screenok = $(window).height();
     $(document).scroll(function() {
     if ($(this).scrollTop() < screenok/3) {
            $("#miao").slideUp(200);
        } else {
            $("#miao").slideDown(200);
        }

    });
```

**CSS**

```
          #miao{ height: 100px; 
          width: 100%; 
          position: fixed; 
          top: 0px;  
          left:0px; 
          z-index:20; 
          background:white; margin:auto; display:none;}
```

JSFIDDLE LINK

https://jsfiddle.net/vtxLqjkw/1/

Thank you very much

Comment: Which `div` do you need to be hidden when starting up? Actually, the `div` with content `CIAO` is hidden.

Comment: I need the div content ciao is hidden at the start and slide down while scrolling down.

Comment: Both your CSS and JS looks fine, the problem might be you linked many different versions of jQuery library in the fiddle, also make sure code runs by using .load() or .ready() if it's in head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of keeping `display:none` in the default styling of the element, you can remove that property from your CSS and call `.hide()` on it on `$(document).ready()` like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var screenok = $(window).height();

  // hide the element initially
  $("#miao").hide();
  $(document).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() < screenok / 3) {
      $("#miao").slideUp(200);
    } else {
      $("#miao").slideDown(200);
    }
  });

});
```

The `.hide()` function sets `display:none` on the element, so it's effectively doing what your style is doing, just not making it a permanent property value.

Comment: You could also put the display:none; as an inline style to prevent a flash of the div before the ready event runs.

Comment: Do you mean to put the style directly on the html?

Comment: Yeah, @NOBrien is suggesting using `<div id="miao" style="display:none;">CIAO</div>` in your initial HTML so the div is already hidden before the javascript runs.  This is where `.hide()` puts that style, so it accomplishes the same goal a little bit sooner in case you're seeing the div for a split second as the page is loading